# DotNetty, не понятен принцип работы асинхронных запросов

Tags: c#, .net, netty

`DotNetty` - порт явского `Netty` (NIO client-server framework), поддерживается командой MS Azure: https://github.com/Azure/DotNetty

Возьмем, например, обычный TCP сканер портов.

**Основной код запуска задач:**

```
private async Task CheckServers(int concurrencyLevel, int port, int timeout)
        {
            var group = new MultithreadEventLoopGroup();

            var tasks = new Task[concurrencyLevel];
            for (int i = 0; i < tasks.Length; i++)
                tasks[i] = CheckIP(port, timeout, group);

            await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
            await group.ShutdownGracefullyAsync();
        }

private async Task CheckIP(int port, int timeout, MultithreadEventLoopGroup group)
        {
            foreach (var ip in ipCollection.GetConsumingEnumerable()) // некая коллекция, которая подает IP адреса
            {
                if (await PortScanner.IsOpenPortAsync(ip, port, timeout, group))
                    Logging.Add(ip + ":" + port.ToString());
            }
        }
```

**И сам класс, который проверяет порт с помощью DotNetty транспорта:**

```
internal class PortScanner
    {
        internal static async Task<bool> IsOpenPortAsync(string ip, int port, int timeout, MultithreadEventLoopGroup _group)
        {
            var result = false;

            try
            {
                var bootstrap = new Bootstrap();
                bootstrap
                    .Group(_group)
                    .Channel<TcpSocketChannel>()
                    .Option(ChannelOption.TcpNodelay, true)
                    .Option(ChannelOption.ConnectTimeout, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timeout))
                    .Handler(new ActionChannelInitializer<ISocketChannel>(channel =>
                    {
                        IChannelPipeline pipeline = channel.Pipeline;
                        pipeline.AddLast("framing-enc", new LengthFieldPrepender(2));
                        pipeline.AddLast("framing-dec", new LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder(ushort.MaxValue, 0, 2, 0, 2));
                        pipeline.AddLast("echo", new EchoClientHandler());
                    }));

                IChannel clientChannel = await bootstrap.ConnectAsync(IPAddress.Parse(ip), port);
                result = clientChannel.Active;
                await clientChannel.CloseAsync();
            }
            catch
            {
                result = false;
            }

            return result;
        }
}
```

И хандлер, в соответствии с требованиями DotNetty:

```
internal class EchoClientHandler : ChannelHandlerAdapter
    {
        public EchoClientHandler()
        {
        }

        public override void ChannelActive(IChannelHandlerContext context)
        {
        }

        public override void ExceptionCaught(IChannelHandlerContext context, Exception exception)
        {
            context.CloseAsync();
        }
    }
```

**Вопрос:** по какой-то причине (моя ошибка\архитектурная ошибка\баг самой библиотеки) - сканер не работает как нужно, запросы моментально отрабатывают (такое ощущение что вместо ожидания завершения подключения от `await bootstrap.ConnectAsync` - метод не ждет окончания подключения к IP адресу, а сразу переходит к `await clientChannel.CloseAsync`). В чем причина подобного поведения?